# How to do a colored grid in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization

Suppose I have a matrix object in R with the values:

```
aa <- matrix(c(0,4,1,10,3,2,1,6,0), ncol=3)
```

And I want to make a figure like the one in the image, with that scale.

Can anyone help me with a function that can help me to do this type of figure in R? or the name of that type of figure-plot-colored-grid?

[image: How can I do this in R?]

Comment: Try look into ?heatmap and the pheatmap package.

Comment: I tried to post it in Stack Overflow but I don't have rep points there, and you need 10 reputation points to post images.

Comment: By the way, I try with the 'image' function but I found a easier way to do it in excel with "conditional formatting". :) Thank you all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the `image` function.  For the scale you will probably want the `colorscale` function in the plotrix package.  There are other functions that can also be used for these types of graphs: `rasterImage`, `levelplot` in the lattice package, etc. You could even create it from scratch using multiple calls to `rect` and other functions if you want complete control.  But `image` is probably the quickest/easiest for what you show.

Answer (score 5):

Or you could use package `raster`.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(xmn = 0, xmx = 3, ymn = 0, ymx = 3, nrows = 3, ncols = 3)
r[] <- 1:9
plot(r)
```

[image]